# Get warning when a variable is shadowed

Tags: c, variables, warnings, c99

I generally want to avoid code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

  int n = 3;

  for (int n = 1; n <= 10; n++){
    printf("%d\n", n);
  }

  printf("%d\n", n);
}
```

How can I find such usage of variables? That means, that in the same function a "more local" variable has the same name as a more global variable?

C-Standard : C 99

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Both gcc and clang support the `-Wshadow` flag which will warn about variables that shadow one another. For example the warning I receive from `gcc` for your code is the following:

```
warning: declaration of ‘n’ shadows a previous local [-Wshadow]
for (int n = 1; n <= 10; n++){
         ^
warning: shadowed declaration is here [-Wshadow]
int n = 3;
    ^
```

`gcc` documents the flag [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) and says:

> Warn whenever a local variable or type declaration shadows another
>   variable, parameter, type, class member (in C++), or instance variable
>   (in Objective-C) or whenever a built-in function is shadowed. Note
>   that in C++, the compiler warns if a local variable shadows an
>   explicit typedef, but not if it shadows a struct/class/enum.

In Visual Studio this looks like it was not possible before but [seems to be fixed in recent versions](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/799873/detection-of-variable-shadowing-should-be-part-of-the-regular-c-compile-instead-of-analyze).