# redefinition of variable inside scope

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++

Why does the following code compiles, under g++, with out any warning or error?
The problem I see is that the variable x defined in the first line is accessible inside the if scope but in spite that it's redefined again.

```
int main() {
    int x = 5;
    std::cout << x;
    if (true) {
        int x = 6;
        std::cout << x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Variable shadowing is what you're looking for.

Comment: [Note you can use -Wshadow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25151524/1708801) to catch this.

Answer (score 7):

According to `C`-

> 6.2.1 in C99:
>
> If the declarator or type specifier that declares the identifier appears inside a block or within the list of parameter declarations in a function definition, the identifier has block scope, which terminates at the } that closes the associated block

...

> If an outer declaration of a lexically identical identifier exists in the same name space, it is hidden until the current scope terminates, after which it again becomes visible.

In both C and C++ it is legal for the same name to be used within multiple scopes.

So in your code the previous `i` remains hidden till the scope of `if` statement terminates.

Answer (score 4):

C++ standard allows name hiding, that means that you can declare anything with same identifier in nested scopes.

From [N4296](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf):

**3.3.10  Name hiding [basic.scope.hiding]**

> 1. A name can be hidden by an explicit declaration of that same name in a nested declarative region or derived class.
> 2. A class name (9.1) or enumeration name (7.2) can be hidden by the name of a variable, data member, function, or enumerator declared in
>      the same scope. If a class or enumeration name and a variable, data
>      member, function, or enumerator are declared in the same scope (in any
>      order) with the same name, the class or enumeration name is hidden
>      wherever the variable, data member, function, or enumerator name is
>      visible.
> 3. In a member function definition, the declaration of a name at block scope hides the declaration of a member of the class with the same
>      name; see 3.3.7. The declaration of a member in a derived class
>      (Clause 10) hides the declaration of a member of a base class of the
>      same name; see 10.2.
> 4. During the lookup of a name qualified by a namespace name, declarations that would otherwise be made visible by a using-directive
>      can be hidden by declarations with the same name in the namespace
>      containing the using-directive; see (3.4.3.2).
> 5. If a name is in scope and is not hidden it is said to be visible

**1 item** of the list is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The second `x` variable has a block scope and is shadowing the previous `x` declaration.

Answer (score 0):

The `x` you are using to print in the last line of your code, belongs to `if` block. This `x` hides the first `x` declared in first line. This is because the scope.

```
int main() {
    int x = 5;    //Accessble throughout the main.
    std::cout << x;
    if (true) {
        int x = 6;   //Local to this if block. Not accessible outside if block
        std::cout << x;   //Prints local x's value

    }
}
```