# Access to redefined variables inside a nested block

Tags: c++

Consider the program below:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
int i = 10;

int main() {
     int i = 9;
     {
          int i = 8;
          {
                int i = 7;
                cout << i << "\n";   // i = 7
                cout << ::i << "\n"; // i = 10 (global i)

                // How could we access to other i declarations here?
          }
     }
     return 0;
}
```

using `i` inside the nested block referes to the last declarations of `i`, because the latter hides the other declarations. In order to use the global `i` (the declarations outside the function main), we could use `::i`

I would like to know if there is a way to use the other decalarations of `i` inside the nested block.

Comment: In short: It's not possible. So just don't do it.

Comment: There is no way, use different names if you need to access outer scope variable

Comment: Why would you write code like this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31937168/5847906

Comment: @CodyGray, Just curiousity :)

Answer (score 0):

Declare a new variable name, something like 'j' instead of 'i'.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
int i = 10;

int main() {
     int i = 9;
     {
          int j = 8;
          {
                int j = 7;
                cout << j << "\n";   // j = 7
                cout << ::i << "\n"; // i = 10 (global i)

                // How could we access to other 
       i declarations here?
          }
     }
     return 0;
    }
```