# Is there a GCC flag to emit warning about identical variable redefinition inside scope?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-warnings, redefinition

As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31937132/3258851), the following is valid C code:

```
int test = 10;
if (true) {
    int test = 10;
}
```

I'm wondering if there's a flag to warn in cases like that, where the redefinition is identical.

Comment: @Olaf Wow. Granted, I could read it, but there would be no value to the community, would it. And btw, the C++ tag _is_ valid. See the related question I linked to.

Comment: There is no value to the community anyway with such questions (it is also a lame excuse), because that would be obviously the first thing to search. gcc is well documented and the documentation can't be easier to find: `gcc documentation`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is: [`-Wshadow=local`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html). Passing in a different value (instead of "local") also allows more precise control over which identifiers can and can't be shadowed.

It checks whether the name is the same, which is a good enough approximation.

Answer (score 2):

> -Wshadow 
>   Warn whenever a local variable or type declaration shadows another variable, parameter, type, or class member (in C++), or
>   whenever a built-in function is shadowed. Note that in C++, the
>   compiler will not warn if a local variable shadows a
>   struct/class/enum, but will warn if it shadows an explicit typedef.

Source: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html