# Why does the compiler parse this as a function pointer and not a recursive call?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

In this following code `foo()` is parsed in two different places and calls two different functions (marked by the `********`).

```
#include <cstdio>

typedef int (*func)(void);

int bar()
{
    printf("bar\n");
    return 4; // guaranteed to be random
}

int foo()
{
    printf("foo\n");
    static int i = 0;
    if(i)
        return i;
    ++i;
    i = foo(); // recursive call     ********
    printf("%d\n", i);
    func foo = bar;
    i = foo(); // calls bar. Why?    ********
    printf("%d\n", i);
    return i;
}

int main()
{
    return foo();
}
```

In all the compilers I was able to try ([gcc, clang](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEJNJb0AGTy1MAOWMAjTMTMBOUgAdUCwuto9QxNBHz81Ohs7RyMXN05FZUxVAIYCZmICIONTcyUVCNo0jIIoh2dXD0V0zOyQhIUa0tty2MrOAEpFVANiZA4AcikAZltkQywAanFhnWRG/FQZ7HEABgBBNfWCAE8vTCwqSdsCSYgAKioDWmQOiAA3VDx0DpnZDa2TyacMiFePgDs73Wk1Bky8xBOVAgUkkP2I4gArDpaLDXsNgWDJsRMARerRJtw3pMAPQkybAAwZEQETAHSZEb6YbEidCoIxbcQAgAinI2XxoqD%2BnKBWyxEKhMMkkkFSJRaLeYrBjWYamQx3ox2mw25k1Wio2WLw0Lw/xBWLBOLxxAJeAN5tBcjkdoxStBeG1usFwoxpPJOOQvT892ZLFYrDd4Mh9GhsKkiPQctR0tIx3RmLBVxuk0Fnu%2BGXtRrz3vTfsmYdYCnzCMNYIlMalknjieRyfMacLltx%2BOO9q5vI%2B/M1RmYtmFgIzoKtPZLfZ5Ay6rBAA0RA1IpgGqzXqGXOidMkmCh6fWZI04a4Iy63HS6AGszIihMvuGuN1vSDuBmuFCBVqRL5uC6kHAsBIGgRheHg7BkBQEDgZB0EgMA7jmFQUG0sQP4QE4V5rk4tgZDsy7nqQ4FGFoBAAPK0KwRGAaQWAjqI7C4QxeABmoIY/vRmAAB7JAYtLEWuJzKKxrB4E4xCEXoWDCf%2BkJGMJXQ0PQTBsBwPD8IIwiiCg%2B7yBJTg/pAXSoF4hTcQAtAA6mwrCTFZ%2BzoDSeDIN%2BSQpBoECWHUpgJJYZQxHEoS%2BP4dB%2BaF4QBEFFTxIkBSpE0kUNJ5hTFJksVtPFKq1PoOSCLlzTRHFXBdEevT9GVT4rq%2BrGfrxAAcABsVnNdwFLIOq7gAHSSGcuCECQ0ySMMCSTHoEFQa4I1jR0E0GReuE3qQ96SI%2BS4DC%2B671cu36/v%2By3ATAiAgHxAlEDBlAZMACgAAoiMoDAIKgADuG4kfBUGqgED12Kwz1vW%2Ba5fYhyHmKDriUYJgPvax53IOsxC3XtFj8cgaT4Bua6qYwYaabwAgJLpYgGUIkkmX8H4WQE3HfseVUNAQWN/U9L1wwM56Lsuq47fRDUtW1HXAF1ky9f12Do4Jw0QINl2zZ0C0yHIS2ASta0bc%2BdX86jP5/gB17HfAEBgeyCGuOQlCQ244wiMAAD6BDENct6kGhrAYVhOH0fhtCEfJZEUdRtGsYxdssfR%2BAcXgXHw1LQmcyJ9BifRRnScQOyyYMJFO3gSmJypdB4xpXCE2YQh2/pysyOTxnwGZNN0NZdnho5zmue5CXJIUmjaClFjaFlIUJGE4WBPl9TeGFhRD%2B0XdeUUyUT/58/pU0s85UvwQr0VG/VRVJ7VZtvPAx%2By5Na17XliTZxOy782y/g8tnqmk3m8Qs2SPNe7V9IqvXneB8NVtqn0/PtfWy1uYDEkNrd8YDDpqy6CGTCAQQDcCAA%3D%3D%3D), MSVC, and a couple others), the output is:

> foo
>   foo
>   1
>   bar
>   4

Why does the compiler choose to call `bar` via the function pointer and mask a recursive call? Is this behavior defined? If so, can I please have a reference?

Comment: `func foo = bar;` means that the second call to `foo` calls `bar`.

Comment: Why should it be different to `int i = 5; { int i; i = 6; } assert(i == 5);`?

Comment: Looks like regular name shadowing to me. `foo` at local scope shadows `foo` at global scope.

Comment: @Nicol Thank you for the duplicate. Exactly what I was looking for (specifically, 3.3.10.2).

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I didn't know that variable hiding was relevant to functions.

Comment: @AviGinsburg - The thing to take away from this is that it isn't variable hiding, it's *name* hiding. Doesn't matter much usually what the name refers to.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica why do you specify “usually”? When does it matter?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, this behavior is defined and is called name hiding, scope hiding, or shadowing. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31937168/12270289) by Victor Polevoy, relevant section quoted below.

> From [N4296](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf):
>
> **3.3.10  Name hiding [basic.scope.hiding]**
>
> > 1. A name can be hidden by an explicit declaration of that same name in a nested declarative region or derived class.
> > 2. A class name (9.1) or enumeration name (7.2) can be hidden by the name of a variable, data member, function, or enumerator declared in
> >        the same scope. If a class or enumeration name and a variable, data
> >        member, function, or enumerator are declared in the same scope (in any
> >        order) with the same name, the class or enumeration name is hidden
> >        wherever the variable, data member, function, or enumerator name is
> >        visible.
> > 3. In a member function definition, the declaration of a name at block scope hides the declaration of a member of the class with the same
> >        name; see 3.3.7. The declaration of a member in a derived class
> >        (Clause 10) hides the declaration of a member of a base class of the
> >        same name; see 10.2.
> > 4. During the lookup of a name qualified by a namespace name, declarations that would otherwise be made visible by a using-directive
> >        can be hidden by declarations with the same name in the namespace
> >        containing the using-directive; see (3.4.3.2).
> > 5. If a name is in scope and is not hidden it is said to be visible

In this case it is also point 1: the declaration of the name `foo` in the function is hiding the declaration of the function name `foo` in the outer scope.

Comment: When you copy something, you need to block quote it.  Also, if you copy something, and all/most of your content is that copied content, then that is plagiarism, even if you cite it.

Comment: no what is happening here is not point 3. We are not in a member function and what is shadowed is not a declaration of a member of a class.

Comment: right, misread the snippet @formerlyknownas_463035818

Comment: no @NathanOliver, it is only plagiarism if I try to pass it off as my own work, which I never made even a slight attempt to do. please see the help articles on the topic and [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160077/users-are-calling-me-a-plagiarist-what-do-i-do) - besides, I literally only quoted the section of his answer that was already directly quoted from the standard.

Comment: @Klaycon Counter point: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/answers-entirely-copied-though-properly-attributed

Comment: @NathanOliver I think it's excessive to invoke that argument when the only original content that ended up copied from Victor's answer was the words "From N4296". However I do agree it's better to have that and the header in the block quote at least, to make it very clear that it was not written by me.

Comment: imho it is rather simple: Did you search the standard to find this quote or did you rather find a different answer that quotes from the standard and copied from that? This does make a difference and in the latter case you should make that clear. Concerning this being just a copy of a different question I do agree: If a different answer is fine for the question here, then rather the question should be flagged as duplicate.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 that is why I decided to attribute the answer in the first place instead of simply using the snippet which, honestly, nobody could reasonably accuse me of not searching for myself had I just quoted it and not explicitly pointed out my source. regardless, your point about the question needing to be a duplicate is fully valid, I had misunderstood it at first to be a more nuanced question or at least having a slightly different answer.