# What happens to assigned values after break statement?

Tags: c, break

This is my code for a certain program. But what is killing me is the fact that in the function `getTotalX`, in the inner **if blocks** of for loops,when **flag is updated to 0**, *after the break statement*, it gets **updated back to 1**. Why is this happening? I thought break statement helps me break from the for loop and continue directly to the next following statement.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int getTotalX(int a_size, int* a, int b_size, int* b){
    int min = a[a_size-1];
    int max = b[0];
    int count = 0;

    for(int i = min; i <= max; i++){
        int flag1 = 1, flag2 = 1;
        for(int j = 0; j < a_size; j++){
            printf("In array a,value of %d mod %d is %d \n",i,a[j],i%a[j] );
            if((i % a[j]) != 0){
                int flag1 = 0;
                printf("flag1 set to 0. Check flag1 = %d\n",flag1);
                break;
            }
        }
        printf("Checkpoint2, value of flag1 = %d\n",flag1);
        if(flag1 != 0){
            for(int k =0; k < b_size; k++){
                printf("In array b,value of %d mod %d is %d \n",b[k],i,b[k]%i );
                if((b[k] % i) != 0){
                    int flag2 = 0;
                    printf("flag2 set to 0. Check flag2 = %d\n",flag2);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        printf("Checkpoint3, value of flag2 = %d\n",flag2);


        if((flag1 == 1) && (flag2 == 1)){
            printf("Value of flag1 = %d and flag2 = %d\n",flag1,flag2 );
            printf("%d \n ",i);
            count++; 
        }
    }
    return(count);

}

int main() {
    int n; 
    int m; 
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);
    int *a = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    for(int a_i = 0; a_i < n; a_i++){
       scanf("%d",&a[a_i]);
    }
    int *b = malloc(sizeof(int) * m);
    for(int b_i = 0; b_i < m; b_i++){
       scanf("%d",&b[b_i]);
    }
    int total = getTotalX(n, a, m, b);
    printf("%d\n", total);
    return 0;
}
```

All the print statements were to help me figure out where I was going wrong. I can change the logic to make it work, but please help me understand why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `int flag1` declared in the `if` block inside the inner `for` is *a different variable* from the `int flag1` declared in the block of the outer `for`. As soon as the second `int flag1` is declared the previous one is *shadowed* and inaccessible by name until the end of the block in which the shadowing declaration occurred.

```
for(int i = min; i <= max; i++){
    int flag1 = 1, flag2 = 1;                 // This is the outer flag1
    for(int j = 0; j < a_size; j++){
        printf("In array a,value of %d mod %d is %d \n",i,a[j],i%a[j] );
        if((i % a[j]) != 0){
            int flag1 = 0;                    // This is the inner flag1
        //  The inner flag1 and the outer flag1 are different variables.
        //  The inner flag1 is set to zero, the outer flag1 is not changed.
            printf("flag1 set to 0. Check flag1 = %d\n",flag1);
            break;
        }
        // The brace ending the block ends the scope of the inner flag1.
        // From now on the name flag1 refers to the outer flag1.
    }
```

Comment: The benefits of [`-Wshadow`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25151524/get-warning-when-a-variable-is-shadowed) cannot be underestimated.

Comment: Oh great!! Wow.