# inner increment i++ output unchanged result

Tags: c

I am following the book "C Primer Plus" and encounter such a snippet of code:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 30;

    printf("x in outer block: %d at %p\n", x, &x);
    {
        int x = 77; // new x , hides first x
        printf("x in inner block: %d at %p\n", x, &x);
    }
    printf("x in outer block: %d at %p\n", x, &x);
    while (x++ < 33) //original x
    {
        int x = 100;
        x++;
        printf("x in while loop: %d at %p\n", x, &x);
    }
    printf("x in outer block: %d at %p\n", x, &x);

    return 0;
}
```

It outputs:

```
In [23]: !./a.out
x in outer block: 30 at 0x7ffee7243788
x in inner block: 77 at 0x7ffee7243784
x in outer block: 30 at 0x7ffee7243788
x in while loop: 101 at 0x7ffee7243780
x in while loop: 101 at 0x7ffee7243780
x in while loop: 101 at 0x7ffee7243780
x in outer block: 34 at 0x7ffee7243788
```

It confuse me a lot on

```
x in while loop: 101 at 0x7ffee7243780
x in while loop: 101 at 0x7ffee7243780
x in while loop: 101 at 0x7ffee7243780
```

How could I make it output?

```
x in while loop: 101 at 0x7ffee7243780
x in while loop: 102 at 0x7ffee7243780
x in while loop: 103 at 0x7ffee7243780
```

Comment: variable shadowing considered harmful

Comment: ok, I get it .@sp2danny

Comment: Make x` inside the second `while` loop `static`.   That way, changes of its value will persist between iterations.

Comment: @sp2danny -- that code snippet is specifically designed to show how variables are scoped in C.

Comment: Hint: compile with the `-Wshadow` option. And also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25151524/get-warning-when-a-variable-is-shadowed)

Comment: I remember _C Primer Plus_ as being a pretty good book, but something here gives me reservations: note that you must cast addresses to `void *` before printing to avoid undefined behavior (but maybe this shows up later in the book). E.g. `printf("x in outer block: %d at %p\n", x, (void *) &x);`.

Comment: The whole idea is probably to make you look at the printed address and realize you are dealing with different objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you enter the while loop you reset your inner x value to 100, you can add an outer var, and increment it in the while loop, add its value to the 100.

```
int main()
{
    int x = 30;
    int y = 0;
    printf("x in outer block: %d at \n", x);
    {
        int x = 77; /* new x , hides first x*/
        printf("x in inner block: %d at \n", x);
    }
    printf("x in outer block: %d at\n", x);

    while (x++ < 33) /*original x*/
    {
        int x = 100;/*value resets on every entry to 100*/
        x++;
        x +=y;
        ++y;/*value is incremented on every entry */

        printf("x in while loop: %d at\n", x);
    }
    printf("x in outer block: %d at \n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please format your answer and add some more text. You don't need to copy the whole code, but instead only snippets

Answer (score 3):

It happens because inside the `while` loop scope the variable `x` is redefined each execution to be equal to 100, this shadows the `x` defined outside, and hence you are not incrementing that one 3 times, but the inner one. At each new iteration the *new* x is incremented by 1, and you see 101 in the output.

Answer (score 1):

There is quite a bit of explanation here so

let me **just answer** your question straight "*How could I make it output?*"

```
while (x++ < 33) //original x
{
    //int x = 100;
    static int x = 100;
    x++;
    printf("x in while loop: %d at %p\n", x, &x);
}
```

I'd say read something on `static` variables and in general `storage classes`

Answer (score 1):

In this while loop:

```
while (x++ < 33) //original x
{
    int x = 100; // this x hides the original x
    x++;
    printf("x in while loop: %d at %p\n", x, &x);
}
```

the `x` declared in the loop body hides the original `x` (used as counter in the `while` loop expression). In every iteration of `while` loop you are getting same value `101` of inner `x` because each iteration of `while` loop creates new instance of `x` (inner `x`) which is initialized with value `100` and destroy's at the end of the loop body.

> > How could I make it output?

You can simply make the inner `x` static, if you want its last value to be persist in every iteration of `while` loop:

```
while (x++ < 33) //original x
{
    static int x = 100;
    x++;
    printf("x in while loop: %d at %p\n", x, &x);
}
```