# Unexpected result when changing location of retuurn

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
#include <stdio.h>

int* plusOne(int* digits, int digitsSize, int* returnSize){
    int* result=0;

    if (digits[digitsSize-1]<9){
        *returnSize=digitsSize;
        int* result = (int *)malloc(*returnSize*(sizeof(int)));
        memcpy( result, digits, *returnSize*(sizeof(int)) );
        result[digitsSize-1]= (result[digitsSize-1])+1;
    }

    return result;

}

int main()
{
    int array[3]={1,2,3};
    int* resultSize= malloc(sizeof(int));
    int* result = plusOne(&array,3,resultSize);
    printf("%i",result[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

The code above segfaults at `printf("%i",result[2]);` because result for some reason is 0... However when I put the `return result;` within the if statement then the code works as expected.

Why is this the case? The if would be evaluated and the return would be same regardless in this situation. Is it compiler optimization? (It just skips the if statement?)

Comment: The compiler should also warn about `int* result = plusOne(&array,3,resultSize);` which should be `int* result = plusOne(array,3,resultSize);`

Comment: You should `#include <stdlib.h>` for `malloc()` and `#include <string.h>` for `memcpy()`.

Comment: `int* result = plusOne(array,3,resultSize);` and `int* result = plusOne(&array,3,resultSize);` are the same but yes its good practice to put the address in. Why would compiler warn tho? What kind of warning?

Comment: They're not the same: `array` converts to type "pointer to int"; `&array` has type "pointer to array[3] of int"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two objects with the identifier `result` in your function `plusOne()`.

```
int* plusOne(int* digits, int digitsSize, int* returnSize){
    int* result=0;
    //   ^^^^^^
    if (digits[digitsSize-1]<9){
        *returnSize=digitsSize;
        int* result = (int *)malloc(*returnSize*(sizeof(int)));
        //   ^^^^^^ inner result
        memcpy( result, digits, *returnSize*(sizeof(int)) );
        result[digitsSize-1]= (result[digitsSize-1])+1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

When you return from inside the `if` you return the inner `result`; otherwise you return the outer one.

Hint: [your compiler can warn you about *shadowing*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25151524/get-warning-when-a-variable-is-shadowed).

Comment: Good catch! The int* should not be there for the inner part. Thanks :)