# C SegFault when recursing with an array of pointers

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I've got a function that takes an array of pointers to doubles that divides the array and recurses. Here's a simplified version:

```c
void recurse(double **ptr_array, int N) {
    int n = N / 2;
    double **new_ptr_array = (double **) malloc(n * sizeof(double *));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        new_ptr_array[i] = ptr_array[i]; // segfault here
    }
    recurse(new_ptr_array, n);
    // repeat for 2nd half
}
```

I've found that when the function is initially called the first time, it runs fine, but on the first recursion, I will get a segfault on the assignment (indicated in the code). I tried even accessing `ptr_array[0]` but that didn't work either.

Could someone explain to me why this fails only when recursing?

Comment: I see nothing wrong in the code that you posted. Therefore, I suspect that the problem is in the code that you did not post. Please provide a [mre] of the segfault.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Your suspicion is indeed correct. I tried creating the minimal reproducible example, and it worked, which led me to examine my code again. Turns out my instantiation of the new array was out of scope, and so `null` was actually being passed in the recursion.

Comment: Yes, it is quite common that the process of attempting to create a [mre] actually solves the problem, making the question redundant. :-) That is one of the reasons why it is always encouraged to create one.

Answer (score 0):

As Andreas suggested, the issue was indeed not in the code that I posted. My code actually looked like this:

```c
void recurse(double **ptr_array, int N) {
    int n = N / 2;
    double **new_ptr_array
    if (true) { // some arbitrary condition
        double **new_ptr_array = (double **) malloc(n * sizeof(double *));
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            new_ptr_array[i] = ptr_array[i]; // segfault here
        }
    }
    recurse(new_ptr_array, n);
    // repeat for 2nd half
}
```

I was accidentally creating a new instance of `new_ptr_array` that is outside the scope of the recursive call, and so `null` was actually being passed to the recurse function.

Comment: My MSVC compiler will warn me when I create a variable which shadows another variable. I believe it does this by default. You can probably set your compiler to do the same. See this question for doing this with the compilers gcc/clang: [Get warning when a variable is shadowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25151524/get-warning-when-a-variable-is-shadowed)

Comment: [This](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/122608/clang-warning-flags-for-objective-c-development/124574#124574) SO post also offers some interesting reading if you are interested in more diagnostic compiler flags (at least for clang/gcc).