# declaration shadows a local variable in c

Tags: c, if-statement, variables, cs50, boolean-logic

I am using the cs50 library and ide and when trying to compile this program I get errors saying that the variable 'answer' has already been declared and I don't know how to solve this any answers would be appreciated I am really stuck on this as I have just began to learn how to program the error log is:

```
char.c:9:14: error: declaration shadows a local variable [-Werror,-Wshadow]
        char answer = get_char("are you okay")

char.c:6:10: note: previous declaration is here
    char answer;

char.c:20:12: error: variable 'answer' is uninitialized when used here [-Werror,-Wuninitialized]
    while (answer != 'y' && answer != 'Y' && answer != 'n' && answer != 'N');

char.c:6:16: note: initialize the variable 'answer' to silence this warning
    char answer;
```

The code is:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{   
    char answer;
    do
    {
        char answer = get_char("are you okay Y/N ");
        if (answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y')
        {
            printf("you are okay");
        }
            else if (answer == 'n' || answer == 'N')
        {
            printf("you are not okay ");
        }

    }
    while (answer != 'y' && answer != 'Y' && answer != 'n' && answer != 'N');
}
```

Comment: Get rid of the `char` prefix on the second `answer` line. With it, you're redeclaring the variable.

Comment: Do we have a canonical question somewhere on variable shadowing in C, explaining at a beginner level what it is and how to avoid doing it by mistake?  I thought we must, but I couldn't find one.

Comment: thank you! this solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the compound statement of the do-while loop you need to use the same variable answer that is declared before the loop.

```
char answer;
do
{
    answer = get_char("are you okay Y/N ");
    if (answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y')
    {
        printf("you are okay");
    }
        else if (answer == 'n' || answer == 'N')
    {
        printf("you are not okay ");
    }

}
while (answer != 'y' && answer != 'Y' && answer != 'n' && answer != 'N');
```

Otherwise this declaration within the compound statement of the do while loop

```
    char answer = get_char("are you okay Y/N ");
```

hides the declaration of the variable with the same name before the while loop and moreover this variable is not alive outside the loop.

Pay attention to that the do-while loop is defined in C the following way

```
do statement while ( expression ) ;
```

For example you may write

```
do ; while ( expression );
```

where a sub-statement of the do-while statement is the null statement `;`.

If you use a compound statement as the sub-statement like

```
do { /*...*/ } while ( expression );
```

then this compound statement forms its one scope and all variables with automatic storage duration are not alive outside the compound statement.

Also instead of call printf like this

```
printf("you are okay");
```

it is better to use a call of puts like

```
puts("you are okay");
```

because the call of puts also appends an output of the new line character `'\n'`.

Answer (score 4):

Note, the warning messages in your post are very helpful.  Do not be shy about simply following their suggestions in-order one-by-one.  (They are what I used to make the suggestions below.)

The *shadow* is caused by the second *declaration* of `answer` inside the `do` block:

```
char answer;// original declaration (the shadow)
do
{
    char answer = get_char("are you okay Y/N ");//2nd declaration (being shadowed)
```

To Fix, do this

```
char answer;// leave this declaration to allow proper scope
do
{
    answer = get_char("are you okay Y/N ");// uses same instance of 'answer' (no shadowing)
^^^^ removed second instance of `char`
```

There is a C specific discussion on [variable shadowing here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25151524/get-warning-when-a-variable-is-shadowed), and another more [broad discussion here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)

Answer (score 0):

try removing the char in

char answer = get_char("are you okay Y/N ");

as it is declared outside the loop

and initilize it to char answer="";

Comment: as per above comments

Comment: `char answer` declares a `char`.  The expression `""` denotes a string literal.  The latter is rarely an appropriate initializer for the former.