# Position of the return statement mattering in C? (variables becoming 0)

Tags: c

I'm new to C, so can someone please explain to me why this returns the expected output

```
int f_to_i(float x) {
        int inc = 0;
        if (x < 0) {
            int inc = 0;
            while (inc > x) {
                inc -= 1;
                return inc;
            }
        }
        else {
            int inc = 0;
            while (inc < x) {
                inc += 1;
                return inc;
            }
        }
    }
```

but this returns 0 no matter what?

```
int f_to_i(float x) {
        int inc = 0;
        if (x < 0) {
            int inc = 0;
            while (inc > x) {
                inc -= 1;
            }
        }
        else {
            int inc = 0;
            while (inc < x) {
                inc += 1;
            }
        }
        return inc;
    }
```

I'm just confused because the only thing that changes is the position of the return statement.  I just started learning C from Ruby, so I'm not used to a lot of these weird features.  If anybody can help me and tell me why this is happening that'd be great.

Comment: Look up "variable scope". Each time you have `int inc` it declares a new variable in a different scope. So the code actually has three `inc` variables and the `return` in each case is returning a different variable.

Comment: Hey could you please provide the full code,I think you may have confused about the ***variable scope***.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I get it now where I made my mistake.  So is it like I had multiple inc variables?

Comment: Do you want to convert the float value to the integer value of that float right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [declaration shadows a local variable in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69302363/declaration-shadows-a-local-variable-in-c)

Comment: @BlueBandicoot Did you get solved your confusion?

Comment: Apart from the variable scope issue, gimme a `break;`

Answer (score 2):

Each time you have `int inc` it declares a new variable in a different scope. So the code actually has three inc variables and the return in each case is returning a different variable.

Here is the code annotated with my comments. Each of the variable scopes is numbered.

```
int f_to_i(float x) {
    int inc = 0; // <--- (1)
    if (x < 0) {
        int inc = 0; // <--- (2)
        while (inc > x) {
            inc -= 1;
            return inc;
        }
    }
    else {
        int inc = 0; // <--- (3)
        while (inc < x) {
            inc += 1;
            return inc;
        }
    }
}
```

In that first example code it is the variable at scope (2) or scope (3) that is returned. In the second example code it is the variable at scope (1) that is returned.

Answer (score 0):

So in the **fist code** stub you have returned the inc value ***inside the conditional statement***. In simple words, it will go inside the `if block(A)` if x<0 and execute only that ***code block(A)*** and come to the end of ***code block (C)*** based on the given float value. As a result, the return statement within the A block with `inc = -1` will be executed. And if x>0, the if condition becomes false, and it enters the `else block(B)` and executes only that code block before exiting the ***B code block*** and reaching the end of ***code block C***. As a result, the return statement within the B block with `inc = 1` will be executed.

```
int f_to_i(float x) {
        int inc = 0;
        if (x < 0) {
            int inc = 0;
            while (inc > x) {
                inc -= 1;
                return inc;
            }
        }// (A)
        else {
            int inc = 0;
            while (inc < x) {
                inc += 1;
                return inc;
            }
        }// (B)
    }// (C)
}
```

However, in the **second code**, you've placed the return statement ***outside of each conditional statement***. Simply stated, you've placed the return statement in the **local scope or block scope**. Because you defined `inc = 0` in the block scope, it returns inc as 0 rather than the value specified by the conditional statements. Because the value inc = 1 or inc = -1 will only be applied within the ***if (A)*** or ***else (B)*** code blocks. After you exit that specific code block inc value is reset to the ***default value provided by the block scope***.

```
int f_to_i(float x) {
        int inc = 0;
        if (x < 0) {
            int inc = 0;
            while (inc > x) {
                inc -= 1;
            }
        }/End of the code block A
        else {
            int inc = 0;
            while (inc < x) {
                inc += 1;
            }
        }//End of the code block B
        return inc;
    }
}
```

I hope this may solve your confusion.If you need more clarification, feel free to ask them.

Comment: While a good discussion of the code paths involved in the function, I suspect the lack of the closing `'}'` is a typo -- as the code would not compile otherwise `:)`

Comment: The scope of the outermost block of a function is not global scope. It is block scope. It is not even file scope, and C has no global scope.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you for your comment.And can i know where is the typo please cause i couldn't find a missing "}".

Comment: Hey! @EricPostpischil Thank you so much for correcting my mistake. I really appreciate it and I corrected them in the answer. Btw the second statement you stated is not right, right? Cause outside of a function known as the global scope isn't it?

Comment: @DininduGunathilaka the missing `'}'` would go at the very bottom of the function inline with the start. It looks like the OP just missed copying it into the question. I'll fix it.

Comment: @DininduGunathilaka: The scope outside of any function is file scope. C has file scope, function scope (for `goto` labels), function prototype scope, and block scope. C has no true global scope. In a language with global scope, you can declare a name in one source file and use it throughout the program, even in other source files. You cannot do this in C; to use a name in two source files, you must declare it in each file, and those declarations are then linked together. So this is a combination of file scope (or it can be done partially with block scope) and external linkage.