# Global variables not working in my function

Tags: c, global-variables

### My Main file

[image: My Main file]

### The file where I store global variables

[image: The file where I store global variables]

The 2 files compile well but nothing is printed as I want.

Comment: Although legal, the two separate source files will be compiled separately. While `main()` can refer to `extern int a, b;`, there's nothing preventing changing the other source to define `double a = 3.14; ...` This is why you need to learn the why and wherefore of "header files". The compiler is helpless to help you, and so is the linker... Don't bury `extern` in a source file; use a header file that is `#include`d into both compilations.

Comment: [Here's how to ask a proper "Where's the bug / Fix my code" question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/11107541). Can you please read it and apply what you learn to improve your question? You can also read [ask] for further guidance. Please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why. See [/editing-help](/editing-help#code) for how to format code blocks.

Comment: You are not calling `sum`function from `main`, you are just declaring it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your function `sum(int a, int b)` has argument names that shadow the global variables you are trying to access. Also you need to call the `sum()` function, not just declare it.

Try this instead:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

extern int a;
extern int b;

void sum() {
  printf("Sum is : %d", a + b);
} 

int main() {
  sum();
}
```

Comment: For popular compilers, you can use [-Wshadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25151524/get-warning-when-a-variable-is-shadowed) to emit a warning when a variable declaration shadows one in the enclosing scope.