# How to produce a compilation error when a class member shadows a class member of its parent?

Tags: c++

I have the following C++ struct:

```
struct Sentence
{
    std::string raw;
    Status      status;
};
```

Is there a way to get a compilation error/warning if another struct derived from this one defines a member with the same name?

For instance, I would appreciate a compilation error/warning if I do this:

```
struct NMEA_RMC : public Sentence
{
    UtcTime rmc_utc;
    char    status;
};
```

Because there is a member with the same name (`status`).

---

I have tried using visibility to workaround this, by doing:

```
struct Sentence
{
    std::string raw;

private:
    Status status;

public:
    const Status& getStatus() const { return status; }
    void setStatus(const Status& newStatus) { status = newStatus; }
};
```

But this does not prevent the definition of the `char status` member in the derived class.

---

I have also tried:

```
struct NMEA_RMC : public Sentence
{
    using Sentence::status;

    int  rmc_utc;
    char status;
};
```

Which will, in fact, produce a compilation error:

> conflicts with a previous declaration

But this is not an elegant solution, since it would be required to be done in all derived classes, and for all base class members.

Comment: I use `-Wshadow-field` so my compiler displays a warning if I shadow a member variable in a derived class.  That is a feature of the compiler.  The language — the C++ standard — doesn't require any diagnostic for shadowing a member variable.

Comment: Afaik, `-Werror=shadow-field` works in all clang-based compilers (which excludes gcc etc).

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25151524/get-warning-when-a-variable-is-shadowed